# Was the Triwizard Tournament continued?

Tags: harry-potter, triwizard-tournament

I get that it wouldn't have happened in 1999, but what about 2004, 2009, 2014, or even in 2019. There seems like there isn't any danger, so did they bring it back and if they didn't, why not?

Comment: Why do you say that "there seems like there isn't any danger"? The tournament events themselves are inherently dangerous due to the level of intended difficulty.

Comment: "There seems like there isn't any danger" - I mean, yeah, apart from the giant fire-breathing dragons, the giant freezing-cold lake, the Blast-Ended Skrewts, and the sphinx that threatened to attack Harry if he got its riddle wrong, the Triwizard Tournament wasn't dangerous at all.

Answer (score 1):

## Unclear.

In the Pottermore article nothing is mentioned about it ***stopping***.

> After some, er, accidents (all three champions were injured in 1792), the contest petered out. That was until its revival two centuries later in 1994, when extra safety precautions were added by the organisers.
> <sub>*- [The Triwizard Tournament](https://www.pottermore.com/features/triwizard-tournament-retrospective)*</sub>

This quote to me sounds like they continued:

> The Triwizard Tournament was rocked forever when the Cup turned out to be a Portkey, which took Cedric and Harry to a graveyard far from Hogwarts where Diggory was killed by Peter Pettigrew. Harry managed to escape and return his fellow champion’s body to his family.
> <sub>*- [The Triwizard Tournament](https://www.pottermore.com/features/triwizard-tournament-retrospective)*</sub>

To me this sounds like it was viewed with distaste in the following tournaments, but I cant be sure.